# Rails routes: same controller different routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, tags, routes

In our app we have a `tag` model, such as `red` `yellow` `big` `small` etc. in several categories like `color` and `size` (tag model does have a field `category`). Now, instead of

```
/tags/big
/tags/small
/tags/red
/tags/yellow
/tags
```

we want routes like

```
/size/big
/size/small
/color/red
/color/yellow
/size
/color
...
```

Also, the url helpers should work too, i.e., `tag_path` should yield correct url's
How to do this in routes.rb file? Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

1. need to get the index pages/url_helper work too
2. will_paginate uses tag_path to generate links with page numbers. need to overload tag_path?

Comment: You could change the name by setting the path `resources :tags,        only: [:show],  path: 'size'` and wrap it around a constraint to show /size or /color depending on the content

Comment: can you give an example? And how would this make the url helper work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use route with constraints. Define a class that executes matches with customized conditions. You can search the API with `match` to see details.

I assume that your tag has two columns named "category" and "name".

route.rb

```
match ':category/:name' => 'tags#show', via: 'get', constraints: TagRouteWhiteList.new, as: 'tag'
```

app/models/tag_route_white_list.rb

```
class TagRouteWhiteList
  def matches(request)
    Tag.distinct('category').include?(request.params[:category]) && Tag.distinct('name').include?(request.params[:name])
  end
end
```

In your view, you can use `tag_path(category: @tag.category, name: @tag.name)`

Comment: Thanks. That's inspiring. I chose to use a regex as constraints. Two more issues though: 1. any way to reload the tag_path at all? I use will_paginate which fails to generate the tag_path with category set. 2. how about the index pages such as `/size` and `/color`? I can only get one of them to work. Appreciate it!

Comment: can you edit your question and add some examples? I think you can add another match to support `/size` or `/color`.

Comment: it turned out to be some other conflicts. thanks for helping out. I'll accept your answer.